# Applying image rounded corners to <li>

Tags: css, image, rounded-corners

I was using jQuery plugins to create a rounded corner for my `<li>`, but it was not working on a lot of browsers and didn't support mouse over.

I am wondering what is the best way to use two images (left corner and right corner) as the left and right side with using `<li>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could put Divs inside your li's like so:

```
<li>
  <div class="lefcorner"></div>
  <div class='liContent'>Foo</div>
  <div class='rightcorner'></div>
</li>
```

That way you will both keep your semantics and will also have the cross-browser support of styling DIVs.

Comment: I think it might be invalid to put a div inside of an li, depends on whether you care about that or not.

Comment: It's not how I would do it, but it's not invalid. LIs can take both inline and block-level content.

Comment: According to the W3C HTML validator it's okay in HTML 4.01 loose

Answer (score 1):

The construct that I have seen used most for that is a span inside a link.

so something like:

```
<li><a><span>Your text here</span></a></li>
```

you can then target the span and the link using the hover state of the link:

```
a:hover{some rules here}  
a:hover span{some more rules here}
```

that keeps it kinda semantic, and doesn't add to much junk to the page.